# After uninstalling JPfofiler ( from Ubuntu ) when i run my application in Netbeans,it shows Error

Tags: java, tomcat, jvm, jprofiler

I installed JProfiler, after 2 days i uninstall Jprofiler (in Ubuntu) but when i run my application Netbeans IDE shows following Error:

Error occurred during initialization of VM
Could not find agent library /home/bsoft/jprofiler7/bin/linux-x86/libjprofilerti.so in absolute path, with error: /home/bsoft/jprofiler7/bin/linux-x86/libjprofilerti.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

Please help me to solve this problem.

### Finally i solved the problem.

i just removed two files(startup_jprofiler.sh, setenv.sh) from my  tomcat installation directory(/var/lib/tomcat6/bin).**

Answer (score 0):

Please first make sure that, your JVM is working or not. Try to start JVM from command prompt. It you are able to launch java.exe file then there are some problems with your project.

You are using netbeans. So before starting netBeans remove cache of netBeans. There are changes that your netBeans is pointing to old class path of jProfiler.

Regards,
Gunjan.